# Swift 3 can't pass variable from tableView to detailView

Tags: swift

I am trying to pass the cell name to next view (detailView) but always get this error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with `iOS` Programming? Because while initiating the `UIViewController` in other class does not initiate it's `IBOutlet`. Please take some `variable` and assign value to it and later on you can access in `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: do you mean I can't access the IBOutlet of DetailView?

Comment: Nope because they are not initialized.

Comment: thank you. I passed a variable instead and then on the didLoad of the DetailView, I assigned it to the label.text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time that `prepare(for segue...` is called, your outlets have not been assigned yet. Your view must be loaded before your outlets are assigned. You can force the view to load simply by accessing it (`detailView.view`), but this is a bad idea. A better approach would be to assign another property on your view controller with the value you're trying to pass around, then in `viewDidLoad` of your detail view controller, set the properties you wish to set on your IBOutlets.